# Html form send array to php

Tags: php, html

I am trying to send arrays  from a html form.
Long story short is a html search form. The below example is for 2 rooms.

The selectors are duplicated based on the numbers of rooms selected

Lets say that HTML from my page is

```
  //ROOM 1
<div  class="selector">
    //adult selector
    <select id='adults-1' name="rooms[]" class="full-width">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
</div>

//ROOM 2
  <div  class="selector">
    //adult selector
    <select id='adults-2' name="rooms[]" class="full-width">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
    //Kids selector
    <select id='kids-2' name="rooms[]" class="full-width">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
   <select id='age-2' name="rooms[]" class="full-width nodisplay">
    <option value="1">3</option>
    <option value="2">4</option>
    <option value="3">5</option>
    <option value="4">6</option>
    </select>
    </div>
```

Example i select 2 Rooms: First room has one Adult, Second Room has two Adult and one Child who has 4 years selected.:

I need to have :

```
// First Room
      $rooms[] = array(array("paxType" => "Adult"));

      // Second Room
      $rooms[] = array(array("paxType" => "Adult"), array("paxType" => "Adult"), array("paxType" => "Child", "age" => 3));
```

Thanks

Comment: How can you get 3 values from just 2 inputs?

Comment: I'm talking about the **desired** values. You can't have 3xAdult in the parameters when there are only 2 input fields. Each input corresponds to one parameter value.

Comment: So i cant send from one input two parameters?

Comment: No you can't. A `<select>` simply sends the value of the selected option. Giving all the options the same value makes no sense, you can't tell which one they chose. You seem to expect it to use the text of the option as a multiplier, there's no such feature. You could write Javascript to add extra hidden inputs like that.